# How to start New Layout (activity) from ListView

Tags: javascript, java, android

When I click the `ListView`, I'd like to start a new `Activity`

Here is my `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.theheran.listviewicon;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //Declarasi Array Menu dan gambar
    ListView list;
    String[] menu = {
            "@The_Heran",
            "www.theheran.com",
            "Add",
            "Delete",
            "Next",
            "Back",
            "Find",
            "Warning"
    } ;
    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.signal,
            R.drawable.add,
            R.drawable.trash,
            R.drawable.next,
            R.drawable.back,
            R.drawable.find,
            R.drawable.warning
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CustomListView adapter = new
        CustomListView(MainActivity.this, menu, imageId);

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +menu[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      // HERE THE PROBLEM     (Intent)           
                Intent intent = new CustomListView(MainActivity.this,); 
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }

}
```

My `CustomListView`

```
package com.theheran.listviewicon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListView extends  ArrayAdapter<String> {
    //Declarasi
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;

    public CustomListView(Activity context,String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single_data, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            //Load Custom Layout untuk list 
            View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single_data, null, true);
            //Declarasi komponen
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtList);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);

            //Set Parameter Value
            txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

            return rowView;
        }
}
```

Comment: NB: Please Check my "MainActivity.java"  at  //HERE THE PROBLEM -- I dont know what code must I use...

Comment: too old question .Search on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // HERE THE PROBLEM     (Intent)
>                   Intent intent = new CustomListView(MainActivity.this,); 
>                 startActivity(intent);

Here you are trying to use a wrong structure.
Use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way ,

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +position , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent MoveToNext = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Your_Next_Activity.class);
                startActivity(MoveToNext);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it. You start a new activity using the `startActivityForResult(intent, 2);` Where you throw a intent and a number (number that you check for when you go back to the starting page).

```
private void registerButtonClickList() {
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {                             

                Intent intent = new Intent(InThisClass.this, GoingToThisClass.class);
                intent.putExtra("Position", position);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });
    }
```

Use this where in the same class as you started the other one form the list. This is needed since you are expecting a return when you start with `startActivityForResult()`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)                   
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0) {                                                                    
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {                                                 
                //See what u should do using the requestCode
                //and check if it ended OK 
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {     
                //what you do when canceled
            }
        }
}
```

And in the activity that you started you need to end with this because you are expected to return something. This you do by using `setResult()`.

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

btnCANCEL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        //intent.putExtra("something", something); if you need to send something back
        finish();
        }
});
```

Hope this helps!